# Jquery hide() not working after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery

The jquery code following :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#cross-sells").hide();
});
```

Please help me.

Comment: where is the ajax call.. where is this code placed

Comment: The code in `ready` runs on page load, I suspect you want to hide the element after ajax call completes depending on the response. If you want to hide the element in all cases add `#cross-sells { display: none; }` in CSS or add `$("#cross-sells").hide();` in ajax `success` callback after adding the element in the DOM

Comment: After your Ajax call Success function, place your code

Comment: Instead of javascript to set the initial display state use css like `#cross-sells{display: none;}`

Comment: @ArunPJohny : it's perfect when adding in css. btw, I know the way placing my code after ajax call success function, but I dont want to depend on it. Thank you for your supporting guys.

Comment: @Tushar thank you too

Comment: @VigNesh thank you too

Comment: @LongĐặng Welcome! Please see [ask] with [mcve] before asking next question :)

Comment: Also, please don't use the `java` tag on Javascript questions.